# column-count and adding new items in rows

Tags: css, layout

I am using column-count to show the boxes of different sizes in multiple columns. The issue is when I generate new items dynamically it adds items towards the column. I want to add more items towards the rows so that user don't need to scroll up to see whatever new was added. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/4231/

```
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item">some multi-size text</div>  
  <div class="item">some multi-size text</div>  
...
</div>
```

css

```
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I don't want to use javascript, supported browsers are IE Edge and latest chrome/FF.

Comment: I think the most straightforward way is to add a new `<div class="masonry">` to add the items to, rather than add them to the existing one.

Comment: Did you find any way to solve this?